# Convert integers in a dataframe column to a list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a column of integer values but I can't seem to figure out how to put those values within the column into a list.

So for example,

```
NUMBERS ------> NUMBERS
 1                [1]
 2                [2]
 3                [3]
 4                [4]
 5                [5]
 6                NaN
 7                [7]
 8                NaN
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way.

```
df['NUMBERS'] = df['NUMBERS'].apply(lambda x: [x])
```

However, this is discouraged unless you have a very specific reason, since you lose the vectorisation benefits of `pandas`.

To control behaviour when your value is `np.nan`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'NUMBERS': list(range(1, 8))})

df['NUMBERS'] = df['NUMBERS'].apply(lambda x: [int(x)] if not pd.isnull(x) \
                                               in (6, 8) else np.nan)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a shot. I'm quite new to pandas so what exactly are these vectorisation benefits, a link would suffice if you don't want to go in depth. <3

Comment: Also how do i prevent 'Nan' from being stored in a list while using apply?

Comment: @Blank usually a good idea to include such edge cases in the data.

Comment: So basically, the column also has empty cells with NaN values but I only want the integers in a list and to exclude the NaN's. I'm trying to edit the main question to include this but I can't figure out how

Comment: Thank you!, successfully edit it. When i tried your updated solution I got this error ----> ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe'' ... the contents of the column are of type object. Does that matter?

Comment: Just tried the update again and the ufunc error still occurs ---> ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: I'll give that a shot, I'm working with a dataset with 28000 rows so, simplified the example cus I didn't think anyone would look through something that long

Comment: So the suggestion you gave was mostly correct for me, to fix the ufunc error, i had to use ... `if not pd.isnull(x) else np.nan`.

Answer (score 4):

`numpy` solution

```
df['Num']=df.NUMBERS.values[:,None].tolist()
df
Out[322]: 
   NUMBERS  Num
0        1  [1]
1        2  [2]
2        3  [3]
3        4  [4]
4        5  [5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

#### Array

`df["NUMBERS"].values.reshape(5,1)`, that would give you

```
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5]])
```

which would be an array, which would keep the vectorisation benefit of `pandas`.

#### List of Lists

Or to get a list of lists, you could do:

`[[x] for x in df["NUMBERS"]]`

which would give:
`[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]`

#### DF of Lists

As @piRSquared suggested, you could do:
`df.assign(Numbers=df.Numbers.values.reshape(-1, 1).tolist())`

Which would return another DF with each value as a list:

```
  Numbers
0     [1]
1     [2]
2     [3]
3     [4]
4     [5]
```

Comment: Complete the answer with `df.assign(Numbers=df.Numbers.values.reshape(-1, 1).tolist())`

Comment: Good suggestion @piRSquared, I didnt think of that one.

Comment: That is your answer.  I just wrapped it up so that it produces what OP asked for.  I was going to provide that answer but decided that it was essentially what you were going for.  So instead, I'm providing you with the wrapper that makes it work.  You deserve the credit (-: